# bootstrap-slider not initialized

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-slider

I am trying to use the bootstrap slider from here: https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider. However I am not able to initialize the slider.
My code snippet looks like this:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-switch.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://raw.githack.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider/master/css/bootstrap-slider.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/jquery-ui.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/ol.css'>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/build/ol.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
    <script src="https://raw.githack.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider/master/js/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>    
    <script src="js/bootstrap-switch.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
        <input style='width:80px;' class='opacity' type='text' value='' data-slider-min='0' data-slider-max='1' data-slider-step='0.1' data-slider-tooltip='hide'>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('input.opacity').slider();
    </script>

</body>
```

This gives me simple input type as shown in the figure

[image]

Then if I do:

```
$('input.opacity').bootstrapSlider();
```

This gives me error as:

[image]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try

```
$(function() {
    $('input.opacity').bootstrapSlider();
});
```

to execute code when document is ready.